# OKZoom, jQuery, and Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement okzoom in my rails application but I don't seem to be having much luck.  Everything appears to be ok. I've added the javascript file to my javascripts directory (app/assets/javascripts/okzoom.js) and also tried using the okzoom_rails gem just to err on the side of caution.  The code editor appears to resolve the okzoom function with no problem but when I run the site, I see the following console error:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

And if I use the Chrome debug tools to dig into it, the problem is clearly with my call to okzoom - for some reason the website isn't seeing it.

Here is my application.js file:

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require fancybox
 //= require okzoom
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require_tree .

 $("a.fancybox")
     .fancybox( {
         'transitionIn': 'elastic',
         'transitionOut': 'elastic',
         helpers : {
             title : {
                 type: 'inside'
             }
         },
         beforeShow: function() {
             /*disable right click*/
             $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e){
                 return false;
             });
         }
     });

 $("img.zoomable")
      .okzoom({
         width: 200,
         height: 200,
         round: true,
         background: "#ffffff",
         backgroundRepeat: "repeat",
         shadow: "0 0 5px #000000",
         border: "1px solid black"
      });
```

I have no issues with the fancybox implementation and I followed the same pattern for okzoom but with no luck.  Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Here is the code for zoomable image:
      <%= image_tag(p.file_info.fullPath, class: "zoomable") %>

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that by the time the JavaScript interpreter gets to the line that loads okzoom that okzoom hasn't already been fetched from the server. I would suggest wrapping your code like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.fancybox")
    .fancybox( {
      'transitionIn': 'elastic',
      'transitionOut': 'elastic',
      helpers : {
        title : {
          type: 'inside'
        }
      },
      beforeShow: function() {
        /*disable right click*/
        $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e){
          return false;
        });
      }
    });

  $("img.zoomable")
    .okzoom({
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      round: true,
      background: "#ffffff",
      backgroundRepeat: "repeat",
      shadow: "0 0 5px #000000",
      border: "1px solid black"
  });
});
```

The `ready` event is triggered once all of the website's markup and assets have been downloaded from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Sadly, wrapping it in document.ready did not work.  I'm still getting the same error on the same line of code.

Comment: Interestingly, if I remove //= require okzoom, I no longer get the error.  Javascript still doesn't fire though so I'm not sure what the problem is now.

Comment: It's normally indicated the file and line number where the error occurred. What does it say?

Comment: Ok. When looking at the Sources tab in the Chrome Dev Tools, do you see a .js file for okzoom? If not, you will need to re-insert it in your application.js file.

Comment: Can you post the line that contains the image tag from your erb or haml file to which `img.zoomable` is referring?

Comment: I posted the line of code that refers to my image tag.  I also checked the sources tab in chrome and I do see the ok zoom in my assets folder (with the typical asset pipeline stuff appended to the name).

Comment: Ok. In the gem's documentation, it's indicated that the image must be smaller for the JavaScript library to work, have you set a different `width` CSS property to make the original image smaller such as `width: 40%;`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71201/discussion-between-shane-mcgarry-and-eric-mulligan).